# Custom ESLint rule to ban z.string().url() from zod

Tags: react-native, eslint, typescript-eslint, zod

Under the hood Zod's [`url()`](https://zod.dev/?id=strings) uses `new URL()` to check for validity. Sadly, the `URL` class is broken on React Native and accepts anything so I want to use other means of checking URL validity. How can I implement a `no-restricted-syntax` ESLint rule to ban `.url()` usage (using Typescript as well)?

Here's a broken attempt at this:

```js
'no-restricted-syntax': [
  'error',
  {
    selector:
      "CallExpression[callee.name='z'][callee.object.callee.property.name='string'][callee.property.name='url']",
    message: "Do not use z.string().url(), RN's new URL() doesn't throw on invalid URL.",
  },
]
```

But this is not flagged `z.string().url()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following syntax rule seemed to work for me in the playground:

```js
'no-restricted-syntax': [
  'error',
  {
    selector: "CallExpression[callee.object.callee.object.name='z'][callee.object.callee.property.name='string'][callee.property.name='url']",
    message: "Do not use z.string().url(), RN's new URL() doesn't throw on invalid URL."
  }
]
```

[eslint playground](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.3.3&showAST=es&fileType=.ts&code=JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQyAdAM4xTAB2A5gBQCU1ArlADacgA&eslintrc=N4KABGBECmAeAu0B2ATAzpAXGA2uCU0aANgJZLyYBO0AxgPYC2jyK0Kk%2BAugDT6QAHAIZU00KgHkB8UvSQZsoAoVqMhANXFpZSLFGJDEaeJD7LIaegFcqtaABUAngOh7IjeiivFX%2BAL5mUFTeRHpKBJAAjlb0Rnp4yhAwVFT0VKb45ijWAEY%2BnMq8mVBI9AC0NMZUpLSIKGVojhRCsPHFSeKp6YHK4YlQYj61aW4AwkLExACisAKV2nI4tBM%2B0AB09DkAVnTwa8uT0OubO7VrSEIsALwA5ABeN1xLK0cb27v7L%2Btz9C5U8I5zpdoLcquQAOaPZ6Hb6pP4AoHXG42YiPDL9JIsNBoITg1zYSAAEXoYFK8DAVjEYDuazBSHBAAoAJRrFHMnhgABKADkbmhSdAAO5gACqnIAMsywNkiEgbuT4AALVLCuRgcgANwmpBQoolawKiT8xS4-hAfiAA&tsconfig=&tokens=false)

That site also provides a really helpful AST explorer tool which I was able to use to match your specific call AST.